# How to get the epoch seconds of a timestamp in Python?

Tags: python

I need to convert a timestamp into seconds, use it in a conditional statement and compare it with other timestamps.

I have tried to do it with bash but I simply can't use it in my Python script:

```
date -d "2019-04-05T10:10:16,841" +%s
```

which results in `1554433816`

Comment: look at the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module. Or use a library like [pendulum](https://github.com/sdispater/pendulum) or [arrow](https://github.com/crsmithdev/arrow).

Comment: Please check my answer below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the datetime object for when the epoch started, a datetime object for your string and subtract them as follows.

```
import datetime
epoch = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime("2019-04-05T10:10:16,841", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S,%f")
epoch =  int((dt - epoch).total_seconds())
print(epoch)
#1554459016
```

Comment: why parse ? `datetime` object has a `.timestamp()` method.
`from datetime import datetime; datetime.now().timestamp()`

Comment: OP wants to convert his given timestamp, not the timestamp `now`

Comment: I have tried it but it doesn't work on my version of Python plus i'm using secureCRT so the parser doesn't work

Comment: You should have mentioned it, updated my code to not use dateutil @MohammedDirir

Comment: Cool, please upvote and accept my answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use datutil.parser for your conversion in python.
Tested on 3.6.

```
from dateutil import parser

t = '2019-04-05T10:10:16,841'
parsed = parser.parse(t)
unix_timestamp = int(parsed.timestamp())
print(unix_timestamp)
```

The timestamp function returns a float. I used the integer cast just to cut off the milliseconds, but you could keep them, if needed.

EDIT: Tested on 2.7:

```
from dateutil import parser
import time

t = '2019-04-05T10:10:16,841'
parsed = parser.parse(t)
unix_timestamp = int(time.mktime(parsed.timetuple()))
print unix_timestamp
```

Note: mktime() returns a float, but without milliseconds.

Comment: I tested this on 3.6. I think in 2.7 you can't do parsed.timestamp(), therefore this wouldn't work in 2.7. But I'll edit the answer for 2.7 in a minute.

Comment: @MohammedDirir I added a solution for 2.7 in my answer.

Comment: i keep getting the same error File "/asp_share/linopt/python/asp-lib/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/parser.py", line 1008, in parse

Comment: return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)
  File "/asp_share/linopt/python/asp-lib/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/parser.py", line 395, in parse
    raise ValueError("Unknown string format")

Comment: what dateutils version do you use? I used "Name: dateutils
Version: 0.6.6" installed via "sudo python -m pip install dateutils". Mind the "s" at the end of dateutils. Maybe there is a dateutil package also.

Comment: i'm using secureCRT i don't think i have that installed and i don't have the admin access to install it unfortunately

Comment: Too bad. Then you have to find a way without installing the dateutils package or get your admin to install it. Or you create a virtual python environment. There you don't have to be root to install packages.

Comment: can you please how i can create a virtual environment that would solve this issue that i have

Comment: I did that only for linux based systems. You can read about it here: https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/virtualenv/ But since you don't have root privileges the package has to be already on your machine. Maybe you're lucky. If the article doesn't fit your requirements you'll have to do some further research.